# How can I schedule a Python script to terminate?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, psycopg2, terminate

I'm currently using python to loop through heavy processing tasks on tables in our database. In order to be friendly to other users I want this processing to only happen during nocturnal hours. When the early risers start using the database, I want to be able to program the premature termination of this script.

I'm aware of [interrupting cow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/interruptingcow/) so I could have something like this:

```
from interruptingcow import timeout

from dbsettings import dbsetting

con = connect(database=dbset['database'],
              host=dbset['host'],
              user=dbset['user'],
              password=dbset['password'])
cursor = con.cursor()

YEARS = {"2014":range(1, 13),
         "2015":range(1, 13)}

def update_table(yyyymm, con, cursor)
     table = 'public.tablename'+yyyymm
     cursor.execute('Do something on {table}'.format(table))
     con.commit()

try:
    with timeout(57600, exception=RuntimeError):
        for year in YEARS:
            for month in years[year]:
                yyyymm = get_yyyymm(year, month)
                update_table(yyyymm, con, cursor)
except RuntimeError:
    print "It's morning, killing database processing"
```

But is this a best practice? Is there a better way?

Comment: Possibly implementing something along these lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python

Comment: If its required, you can add some persistence and when ￼the program starts again, it does from the last good state. [`Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)  could be an option.

Comment: @JoseRaulBarreras I'll look into that, at the moment going to try something based on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14924210/4047679

Comment: Running into serializabity issues, pickle might not work?
for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461901/debugging-pickle