# python share thread-objects in manager.dict() between 2 processes

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

I want to share a dict of thread-objects between 2 processes. I have also another dict of objects which seems to work at the moment.

The problem is that it raises an exception when I try to add key/value pairs to the dict (`key` is an integer and `value` is the thread-object):

```
Exception with manager.dict()
    TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

I try to switch from `manager.dict()` to `manager.list()`, it does not work either:

```
Exception with manager.list()
    TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

The `readFiles()` function is working correctly.

I use python 3.5.1 (Anaconda)

```
def startAlgorithm(fNameGraph, fNameEnergyDistribution, fNameRouteTables):
    global _manager, _allTiesets, _allNodes, _stopDistribution

    _manager = Manager()
    _allTiesets = _manager.dict()
    _allNodes = _manager.dict()

    _stopDistribution = Value(c_bool, False)

    readFiles(fNameGraph, fNameEnergyDistribution, fNameRouteTables)
    initializeAlgorithm()

    procTADiC = Process(target=TADiC, args=(_stopDistribution, _allNodes))
    procTA = Process(target=TIESET_AGENT, args=(_stopDistribution, _allNodes, _allTiesets))
    procTADiC.start()
    procTA.start()

    procTADiC.join()
    procTA.join()


def initializeAlgorithm():
    global _graphNX, _routingTable, _energyDistribution, _energyMeanValue

    #Init all Nodes
    allNodeIDs = _graphNX.nodes()
    energySum = 0
    for node in allNodeIDs:
        nodeEnergyLoad = float(_energyDistribution.get(str(node)))
        nodeObj = Node(node, nodeEnergyLoad)
        _allNodes[node] = nodeObj
        energySum = energySum + nodeEnergyLoad

    #Calculate the mean value from the whole energy in the graph
    _energyMeanValue = energySum / len(allNodeIDs)

    #Init all Tieset-Threads
    for tieset in _routingTable:
        tiesetID = int(tieset['TiesetID'])
        connNodes = list(tieset['Nodes'])
        connEdges = list(tieset['Edges'])
        adjTiesets = list(tieset['AdjTiesets'])
        tiesetThread = Tieset(tiesetID, connNodes, connEdges, adjTiesets)
        _allTiesets[tiesetID] = tiesetThread        # Raise Exception!!!!!!!!!!


class Node:
    'Node-Class that hold information about a node in a tieset'

    def __init__(self, nodeID, energyLoad):
        self.nodeID = nodeID
        self.energyLoad = energyLoad
        self.tiesetFlag = False


class Tieset(threading.Thread):
    'Tieset-Class as Thread to distribute the load within the tieset'

    def __init__(self, tiesetID, connectedNodes, connectedEdges, adjTiesets):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tiesetID = tiesetID
        self.connectedNodes = connectedNodes
        self.connectedEdges = connectedEdges
        self.adjTiesets = adjTiesets
        self.leaderNodeID = min(int(n) for n in connectedNodes)
        self.measureCnt = 0


    def run(self):
        print('start Thread')
```

Comment: What exception are you getting? Add the exception trace to the question.

Comment: When I use dict() it raise the exception... TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object

Comment: when i use list it raise the exception... TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can say that you can't share threads between processes, you can share arguments for those threads if you want to start them in different processes, or you can share some results. The problem you are seeing caused by nature of that process creation, in python all the parameters will be serialized in your current process, then passed to a new one, and then python will deserialize them there to run the "target". Apparently, thread object is not serializable (you can check this interesting thread to understand serialization problem [debugging pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461901/debugging-pickle)).

Comment: Thanks, for this answer, I try to think about how I can handle that in a different way... do I need to pickle the thread-objects anyway when i want to store them in a list(not in manager.list())?

Comment: The problem is that thread-objects are not serializable, you can implement your own serializer/deserializer tho, but you can't use the same thread in another process.

Comment: And yes, you can store thread-objects in any structure, there is no problem with that.

Comment: Thanks for this hints, I just change the code that i will pass the routingtable as json-format to the process and create the thread-objects in the process where I need them